# How to add custom image box in wordpress homepage

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to add Image boxes on Homepage of my WordPress website without use of HTML Editor.

Boxes are like : `ssense.com`
I like the design but don't know how to change the code of file.

So can anyone please help me regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn a little bit of html and css, and if You want to place them dynamically, then php also.

Comment: i have created html and css. but which file i add the code? and I want to create a custom plugin like change the photo and text from admin panel

Comment: The example site that you provided isn't a wp site, they're just using jQuery. I agree with @Marcin Bobowski but, if you already have a wp site up and running you should start by browsing the enormous amount of available plugins out there to see if there is something close to the example above.

Comment: If you are trying to actually author the plugin yourself that is different than just implementing the code(as you stated above). Here are a few resource to learn how to create wp plugins: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin - http://wpmu.org/how-to-write-a-wordpress-plugin-12-essential-guides-and-resources/

Comment: There is a great book "Wrox Professional WordPress Plugin Development". It really helps to get into WP plugin development, but You have to know html, css and jQuery before digging into it. Without programming skills, You will not be able to do anything.